# Why is hacking into NORAD with 'just a laptop' that much more impressive?

Tags: live-free-or-die-hard

In the movie Live Free or Die Hard, when introducing the main villain, a hacker by the name of Thomas Gabriel, the character named Warlock who is also a hacker, says this to John McClane and his sidekick to express Gabriel's proficiency as a hacker:

> and, with just a laptop, hacks into NORAD and shuts down our defence
>   network. So they put a gun to the man's head and forced him to stop
>   the hack.
>   Thomas Gabriel's the guy who shut down NORAD with a **laptop** just to
>   prove a point.

why is there an emphasis on the laptop part?  is it really more impressive that he hacked into that organization with a laptop instead of a regular PC?

Comment: in '07 half the world still thought dialup was cool, & laptops even cooler. Time moves swiftly on.

Answer (score 4):

Laptops are (generally speaking, anyway) less powerful machines than desktops, with less room for additional components such as memory and GPUs etc.

A lot of hacking involves `brute-forcing` password, which is where the attacking machine guesses a huge number of passwords in an attempt to gain access to the system.  This can use up a lot of system resource.

That Thomas Gabriel was able to break in with only a laptop is supposed to be an indicator of his skill level.

Comment: Presumably it also means he didn't need to use specialized hacking hardware or social engineering tricks.  To take down something the size of NORAD; you would expect a large organized group of hackers with extreme hardware.

Comment: And it may have not been contrasting laptop to desktop, but laptop to mainframe.

Comment: Technology aside, it probably sounds better to the layperson watching the film.